# SQL help - comparing values across table based on value

Tags: mysql, sql

```
tag | date | $  
1   | 112014 | 1.42  
2   | 112014 | 2.53  
1   | 112015 | 1.42
```

Desired output:

```
col1 - tag  
col2 - earliest date  
col3 - later date  
col4 - $
```

now I want it to show something like:

```
1 | 112014 | 112015 | 1.42
```

want to do this through a query in mysql
please help!
Also if it can check values across two tables - ie check tbl2 against tbl1 data

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can use aggregation functions, alike MAX(), MIN(), AVG(), SUM(), if you need to get only one row per tag, [using grouping](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html).

```
SELECT `col1` as `tag`, MIN(`col2`) as `earliest_date`, MAX(`col3`) as `latest_date`, AVG(`col4`) as `sum`
FROM `tbl1`
GROUP BY `col1`
```

If you need to select all rows, and [sorted by columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html) you provided, then the query might look like this:

```
SELECT `col1` as `tag`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4` as `sum`
FROM `tbl1`
ORDER BY `col2` ASC, `col3` DESC
```

You may use [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html), if you just want to get result from both tables.

If you need to treat data from two tables as one table and to run aggregation on them, then apply concept aggregation/summarize table, alike that:

```
CREATE TABLE `merged_tbl` AS SELECT * FROM `tbl1` UNION SELECT * FROM `tbl2`
```

Then execute the same aggregation query but on the newly created merged table.